# Do we need a [unity3d-mlapi] tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Unity released version 0.1.0 of their MLAPI networking library ([GitHub](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.multiplayer.mlapi)) on March 23 of this year.

[The 9 existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unity+mlapi) about this library either use no specific tag or the [unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet) tag, as MLAPI is the "successor" to Unity's UNet ([UNet Deprecation FAQ](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001252086-UNet-Deprecation-FAQ)). I'm still a bit confused about how separate it is, because a few of their internal classes use the term UNet (e.g. [`UNetTransport`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.multiplayer.mlapi/blob/3e3aef6aa02c2a25359898319e5bd49d3518b57b/com.unity.multiplayer.mlapi/Runtime/Transports/UNET/UNetTransport.cs))

Is it recommended to continue using the [unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet) tag or should [unity3d-mlapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-mlapi) be created? I have enough reputation to create tags and would be willing to add the tag into the 9 questions.